# Laravel unique name but if the id is the same

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation

i am trying to learn laravel.
Now i have a form thats working. I can create and i can update the data.

But i have a special case. I am adding data with a name.
I want this names to be used only one time. Therefore i am using the unique function.
This is working fine when i am creating new things. But when i update the data, and i dont change the name, it gives me an error because the name exists (but its the same entry).

So now, i would like to validate if the name is taken, but if the id is the same so it can be updated.

how can i do this in laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, you can use the `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` class to create a rule object to use in conjunction with other rules. The `Rule` object has an `ignore()` method:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

See "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID":

https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique